# How do I connect to a RDS MySQL instance from RStudio via a bastion host?

Tags: r, rstudio, amazon-rds

I would like to use RStudio for analysis of data on a MySQL instance. This is a AWS RDS MySql instance that is only accessible via a jump box / bastion host. I have the credentials necessary to connect to the jump box, and from the jump box to the RDS instance. What do I need to do be able to query this DB directly from within the RStudio console?

I can connect (using the Terminal tab in RStudio)to the jump box using:
ssh -p 22xx user@ip.add.re.ss

Then I can connect to RDS mysql using:
mysql -u username -p database -h hostname.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com

I can connect and do manual mysql commands from within RStudio terminal, but I don't seem to be able to do anything with the DB from the RStudio console.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for opening a 2yo thread, but for everyone dealing with this issue as I am - I found this thread and it looks like it works (connecting with MySQL via ssh from R Studio).

> You should use something which is called port forwarding. Some details
> are here
> (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding) For
> example, say you wanted to connect from your laptop to
> http://www.ubuntuforums.org using an SSH tunnel. You would use source
> port number 8080 (the alternate http port), destination port 80 (the
> http port), and destination server [www.ubuntuforums.org](http://www.ubuntuforums.org). :
>
> ssh -L 8080:[www.ubuntuforums.org:80](http://www.ubuntuforums.org:80)  Where  should be
> replaced by the name of your laptop.
>
> This is done for whole computer so you dont need to do this from r
> studio.
>
> Offcourse you need to forward your port to 3036. But you need special
> privilige on the server. Because on most hosting you can only connect
> from localhost (for example from PHP)

Source: https://www.py4u.net/discuss/881859